# Is it possible to update the database using Reflection and EF Core's new ExecuteUpdate() method?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I am currently attempting to update the database using Reflection and Entity Framework Core's new ExecuteUpdate() method using the following code:

```
        public async Task<bool> UpdateUserProperty(string username, string property, object value)
        {
            // Using Reflection:
            _TMSContext.Users
           .Where(u => u.UserName == username)
           .ExecuteUpdate(s => s.SetProperty(u => u.GetType().GetProperty(property), value));


            // Trying to use reflection to accomplish this:
            //_TMSContext.Users
            //    .Where(u => u.UserName == username)
            //    .ExecuteUpdate(s => s.SetProperty(u => u.ForceChangePasswordInd, value));

            return true;
        }
```

However, this does not seem to work and throws the following error:

> 'System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'DbSet()
> .Where(u => u.UserName == __username_0)
> .ExecuteUpdate(s => s.SetProperty(
> propertyExpression: u => u.GetType().GetProperty(__property_1),
> valueExpression: __value_2))' could not be translated. Additional information: The following lambda argument to 'SetProperty' does not represent a valid property to be set: 'u => u.GetType().GetProperty(__property_1)'

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Are you trying to update multiple props on the user object?

Comment: Are you trying to change rows of data in database or do a migration (modify the database structure tables/fields)?

Comment: Your method is named `UpdateForceChangePassword`. The name clearly states what will change. So just get rid of reflection.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments. Svyatoslav Danyliv's comment and answer at the provided link was what I was looking for :). Thanks Svyatoslav! I would upvote your comment but I don't have enough reputation yet xD.

Comment: Also, thanks to Alexander Petrov for pointing out the misleading method name. I have now updated this to reflect that I was trying to update a property based on the 'property' string parameter, and not the 'ForceChangePasswordInd' property specifically.